# Compare Combobox value VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have 3 Combobox called: NB1,NB2,NB3 . this Comboboxs has 2 values : " - " or  another text

If the text of each of these combo boxes is equal to each other, it will give an error (msgbox) and the combo box that has " -  " will not be compared.
Example:

| Combo1 | Combo2 | Combo3 | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | A | Error |
| A | A | A | Error |
| A | - | A | Error |
| - | C | A | OK |
| D | B | A | OK |
| - | - | - | OK |
| - | F | A | OK |
| - | D | D | Error |

Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved this problem by AndAlso Structure. " - " will appear when the value of textbox be 0 .

(cb_1.Text = cb_2.Text AndAlso Val(txt_1.Text) > 0)

works fine.

Comment: I would strongly recommend against using `Val` which is a compatibility routine with a lot of quirks to its behavior.  Prefer `Double.Parse` or `Integer.Parse` instead (or with a little more editing you can use `Double.TryParse` or `Integer.TryParse` which may be closer to what you want anyway).